# Derivative of a triple product matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, kronecker-product

I am trying to find the solution for the following derivative
$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E\boldsymbol J\boldsymbol E^{T}}{\partial \boldsymbol E}$$

where $\boldsymbol E$ and $\boldsymbol J$ are both matrices. I tried to search for a solution mainly involving the Kronecker product and found that it could be solved using the chain rule. The problem is that I found two sources giving somewhat different version of the chain rule which I can't manage to check if they are equal. The first one from [here](https://lewisgroup.uta.edu/ee5329/lectures/Brewer%20Kronecker.pdf) gives

$$\frac{\partial (\boldsymbol A\boldsymbol F\boldsymbol )}{\partial \boldsymbol B}=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol A}{\partial \boldsymbol B}(\boldsymbol I\otimes \boldsymbol F)+(\boldsymbol I\otimes \boldsymbol A)\frac{\partial \boldsymbol F}{\partial \boldsymbol B}$$

while the second one from [here](http://paulklein.ca/newsite/teaching/calcvec.pdf) gives
$$\frac{\partial (\boldsymbol A\boldsymbol B)}{\partial \boldsymbol x^{T}}=(\boldsymbol B^{T}\otimes \boldsymbol I)\frac{\partial vec(\boldsymbol A)}{\partial \boldsymbol x^{T}}+(\boldsymbol I\otimes \boldsymbol A)\frac{\partial vec(\boldsymbol B)}{\partial \boldsymbol x^{T}}$$

where I am assuming that the $\boldsymbol x^{T}$ can be seen as $vec(\boldsymbol E)$. Can someone please help me in understanding how these two are equal and at the end, how my original derivative can be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\k{\sum_k}
\def\l{\sum_l}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\B{\Big}\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\B(#1\B)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$The differential of a matrix is easy to work with, since it obeys
all of the rules of matrix algebra. So let's start by calculating
the differential of your function.
$$\eqalign{
 F &= EJE^T \\
dF &= dE\;JE^T + EJ\;dE^T \\
}$$
Vectorizing this expression yields
$$\eqalign{
f &= \vecc{F},\qquad e=\vecc{E} \\
df &= \LR{EJ^T\otimes I}\,de + \LR{I\otimes EJ}K\;de \\
\grad{f}{e} &= \LR{EJ^T\otimes I} + \LR{I\otimes EJ}K \\
}$$
where $K$ is the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with
the `vec()` operation.

Another approach to the problem is to use the self-gradient of a matrix, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\grad{E}{E_{ij}} = S_{ij} \\
}$$
where $S_{ij}$ is the matrix whose components are all zero, except for the
$(i,j)^{th}$ component which is equal to one. This is sometimes called the
*single-entry* matrix, and it can be used to write the
component-wise gradient of the function as
$$\eqalign{
\grad{F}{E_{ij}} &= S_{ij}\,JE^T + EJ\,S_{ij} \\
}$$
Yet another approach is to use [Index Notation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html) to write the self-gradient (which is a fourth-order tensor) in terms of [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) symbols as
$$\eqalign{
\grad{E_{mn}}{E_{ij}} = \d_{im}\d_{jn} \\
}$$
Then calculate the gradient of the function
(also a fourth-order tensor) as
$$\eqalign{
F_{mn} &= \k\l E_{mk}J_{kl}E_{ln}^T   \\
\grad{F_{mn}}{E_{ij}}
 &= \k\l \BR{ \c{\d_{im}\d_{jk}}\;J_{kl}E_{nl}
  + E_{mk}J_{kl}\;\c{\d_{in}\d_{jl}} } \\
 &= \l \d_{im}J_{jl}E_{ln}^T + \k E_{mk}J_{kj}\d_{in} \\
 &= \d_{mi}\LR{JE^T}_{jn} + \LR{EJ}_{mj}\d_{in} \\
}$$
Once you are comfortable with the Einstein summation convention,
you can drop the $\Sigma$ symbols to write the intermediate steps more concisely.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer!

Comment: I'm reading about your first result involving the [Commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) and its use in the Kronecker product., and noted that on the link provided, it shows that for $A$ being an  (m,n) matrix and $B$ and rxq matrix, $$K^{(r,m)}(A\otimes B)K^{(n,q)}=B\otimes A$$ but I see that your answer only have the commutation on the right side of the kronecker product. Am I right to say that in this case, $(I\otimes EJ)K $ is not equal to $(EJ\otimes I)$

Comment: @DarrenDeBattista If either $r$ or $m$ is equal to one (which is the case when working with vectors), then $K^{(r,m)}$ is equal to the identity matrix and can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

We look somewhat more detailed at OPs first identity and calculate
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\left(\boldsymbol {EJE}^{T}\right)}{\partial\boldsymbol {E}}
\end{align*}

The matrix derivation used in OPs first cited *[paper](https://lewisgroup.uta.edu/ee5329/lectures/Brewer%20Kronecker.pdf)*
is based on W.J Vetters definition. Let $X=(x_{ij})$ be a matrix of order $(r\times s)$. Let $Y$ be a matrix of order $(p\times q)$. We define the derivative of a matrix $Y$ with respect to a matrix $X$ as partitioned matrix
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial\boldsymbol{X}}:=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{11}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{12}}&\cdots&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{1n}}\\
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{21}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{22}}&\cdots&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{2n}}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{m1}}&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{m2}}&\cdots&\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{mn}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=1}^{s}\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial\,x_{ij}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The matrix $\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}$ is called *elementary matrix*. It has order $(r\times s)$, a $1$ at position $(i,j)$ and is zero at all other positions.

> Let $\boldsymbol{X}$ be matrix of order $(r\times s)$, $\boldsymbol{Y}$ of order $(p\times q)$ and $\boldsymbol{Z}$ of order $(q\times u)$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial (\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{Z})}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}}
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=1}^{s}\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes
> \frac{\partial\left(\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{Z}\right)}{\partial x_{ij}}\tag{2.1}\\
> &=\sum_{i,j}\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes
> \left(\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{ij}}\boldsymbol{Z}+\boldsymbol{Y}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Z}}{\partial x_{ij}}\right)\tag{2.2}\\
> &=\sum_{i,j}\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes
> \left(\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{ij}}\boldsymbol{Z}\right)+\sum_{i,j}\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes
> \left(\boldsymbol{Y}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Z}}{\partial x_{ij}}\right)\tag{2.3}\\
> &=\sum_{i,j}\left(\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\boldsymbol{I}_s\right)\otimes
> \left(\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{ij}}\boldsymbol{Z}\right)\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{i,j}\left( \boldsymbol{I}_r\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\right)\otimes
> \left(\boldsymbol{Y}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Z}}{\partial x_{ij}}\right)\tag{2.4}\\
> &=\sum_{i,j}\left(\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial x_{ij}}\right)
> \left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{Z}\right)\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{i,j}\left( \boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{Y}\right)
> \left(\boldsymbol{E}_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{Z}}{\partial x_{ij}}\right)\tag{2.5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{Z}\right)
> +\left( \boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{Y}\right)\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Z}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}}\tag{2.6}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) we use the representation (1).
- In (2.2) we use the product rule of derivation.
- In (2.3) we use the identity $(\boldsymbol{A}+ \boldsymbol{B})\otimes \boldsymbol{C}
  =(\boldsymbol{A}\otimes \boldsymbol{C})+(\boldsymbol{B}\otimes \boldsymbol{C})$.
- In (2.4) we use the identity $\boldsymbol{I}_r\boldsymbol{A}^{(r\times s)}=\boldsymbol{A}^{(r\times s)}=\boldsymbol{A}^{(r\times s)}\boldsymbol{I}_s$.
- In (2.5) we use the identity $(\boldsymbol{A}\otimes\boldsymbol{C})(\boldsymbol{B}\otimes\boldsymbol{D})
  =(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{B}\otimes\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{D})$
- In (2.6) we use again the representation from (1).

> Based on the identity (2.6) we consider a matrix $X$ of order $(r\times s)$, $Y$ of order $(s\times s)$ and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial (\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{X}^T)}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}}
> &=\frac{\partial (\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{Y})}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}
> \left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{X}^T\right)
> +\left(\boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{Y}\right)
> \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}^T}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\\
> &=\left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{Y}\right)
> +\left(\boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{X}\right)\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\right)
> \left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{X}^T\right)\\
> &\qquad+\left(\boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{Y}\right)
> \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}^T}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\\
> &=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{Y}\right)
> \left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{X}^T\right)
> +\left(\boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{X}\right)\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}
> \left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{X}^T\right)\\
> &\qquad+\left(\boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{Y}\right)
> \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}^T}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}\left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{X}^T\right)
> +\left(\boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{X}\right)\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}
> \left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{X}^T\right)}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{+\left(\boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{Y}\right)
> \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}^T}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Hint:* This notation of matrix calculus presented nicely in OPs cited paper by J.W. Brewer can also be found in *[Kronecker Products & Matrix Calculus with Applications](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/kronecker-products-and-matrix-calculus-with-applications)* by A. Graham.

We can simplify (3) somewhat by introducing the *permutation matrix* $\boldsymbol{U}^{(r\times s)}$ which is of order $(r\times s)$ and which has precisely a $1$ in each row and in each column and is zero otherwise.

We get a permutation matrix
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}^T}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}}
&=\sum_{i,j}E_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}^T}{\partial x_{ij}}\\
&=\sum_{i,j}E_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes E_{ji}^{(r\times s)}
\color{blue}{=: \boldsymbol{U}}
\end{align*}
and the related matrix
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}}
&=\sum_{i,j}E_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}{\partial x_{ij}}\\
&=\sum_{i,j}E_{ij}^{(r\times s)}\otimes E_{ij}^{(r\times s)}
\color{blue}{=: \boldsymbol{\overline{U}}}
\end{align*}

> With $\boldsymbol{U},\boldsymbol{\overline{U}}$ expression (3) can be written as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial (\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{X}^T)}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}}
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\boldsymbol{\overline{U}}\left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{X}^T\right)
> +\left(\boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{X}\right)\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{Y}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}
> \left(\boldsymbol{I}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{X}^T\right)}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{+\left(\boldsymbol{I}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{Y}\right)
> \boldsymbol{U}}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed derivation!

Comment: @DarrenDeBattista: You're welcome! :-)